# How to understand python classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

Hello I'm learning python, it is also my first language. I'm trying to figure out how classes work. I have this small code and I can't get it to work after a week of searching. Thank you for helping me.

Also I'm trying to figure out what getattr and super do. I read on the documentation but its not easy for me to understand. English is not my native language and its a little difficult to understand sometimes.If you can explain this two things or if you know any website that explains it in a simple way I would really thank you for it.

here is the code:

```
import sys


class Map(object):
    dicti = {'stuff': stuff(),
             'more_stuff': more_stuff()
    }

    class Stuff:

        def stuff(self):
            print "did it work?"
            next = raw_input("type next: ")

            if next == "next":
                return 'more_stuff'
            else:
                print "what? lets try again."
                return 'stuff'      

    class MoreStuff:

        def more_stuff(self):
            print "ok"

            next = raw_input('type next: ')

            if next == "next":
                return 'stuff'

            else:
                print "bye."
                sys.exit(0)


class NewClass(Map):

    def __init__(self, themap):

        self.themap = themap

    def Continu(self):

        next = self.themap

        while True:
            print "----"

            room = next()




a_test = NewClass('stuff')
a_test.Continu()
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work" -- what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I sorry i did not word correct. It does not work I'm trying to get help understanding why. sorry. It suppose to go through the room using classes and a dictionary, or at least I'm trying to make it do that.

Comment: We understand that it doesn't work -- But in order to understand *why* it doesn't work so we can help you, we need to understand what you expect it to do.

Comment: You seem to be using classes as containers for functions. Avoid doing that - Most functions in a class should relate directly to manipulating or examining an instance of that class (referred to as `self`). Not doing anything with `self`? Probably doesn't belong in a class... Also, consider moving Stuff and MoreStuff classes out of Map; There *are* cases in which nested classes are useful, but these are rare and really something you should only do if you understand classes really well. In this case it's much more likely that you are doing that out of misunderstanding. Keep things simple.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying to understand classes that is why I used so many.

Comment: Making lots of classes is fine, just avoid placing one inside another; it usually does not achieve what you actually want. About `getattr()`: to learn classes, understanding `getattr()` is usually not useful; most ordinary classes never use it. `super()` is sometimes useful in classes, but mostly is not needed (see [this link](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/), if you are willing to get into the technical details.)

Comment: Also it will help people to suggest links if you mention what resources you have already read. For example, have you read [DiveIntoPython's chapter on classes](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html#fileinfo.divein)? -

Comment: I have not read that thank you. I am going through learn python the hard way. I was understanding everything except when i started with classes. The book is good but it doesn't really explain it at least in a way i understand. and i just read random sites when searching classes in google.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string `'stuff'` into `NewClass`, so that is becoming `self.themap`

later you are assigning `next = self.themap`, so now `next` is also a reference to the string `'stuff'`.

`room = next()` will fail because you can't call a string

Comment: Thank you. would i use getatter? if i understand correct here. http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm

Comment: @user2227702: no, there is no attribute you could get the value of that will behave as you wanted; you haven't implemented one.

Comment: Can you recommend any books on oop and python? I'm having a very difficult time understanding. Everything to this point was somewhat easy, but now I'm really stuck. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2227702: see my latest comment on your main post. also 'Learn Python the Hard Way' has some chapters on classes, starting at [part 40](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html)

Comment: @kampu That is the book I'm doing but I guess is updated on the website. I bought it on udemy(dot)com but is an older version. I will continue from the website, it seems like it explains more. thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your class is that it doesn't seem to represent anything (sorry if that's harsh).  Rather than fix your code, I'll just show you a couple examples.

These are example classes that I wrote.  The first one is kind of ridiculous, but actually simple and could teach you something.  It uses `hasattr` which is not a far stretch from `getattr`.

You're classes can have logic in them, but try to see them as ways of managing information about an object.  I mean *object* in both the python sense and in the normal meaning of the word.

Also, I noticed you have some other classes indented under `Map`.  Just work with classes as separate things for now.  Indenting those like that does not give them any special relationship to `Map`

```
class OppMan:

    def __init__(self, awake = False):

        self.truth = awake
        self.answers = 0


    def echo(self, userIn):

        if type(userIn) == (int or float):
            answer = -1*self.truth*userIn

        elif hasattr(userIn, '__str__') or hasattr(userIn, '__repr__'):
            answer = 'not '*self.truth + str(userIn)

        else:
            try:
                answer = -1*userIn
            except:
                answer = 'I am only human'

        self.answers += 1
        return answer
```

Example usage:

```
Barney = OppMan(True)

print(Barney.echo(420))
print(Barney.echo('yours'))
print(Barney.echo(['a','b','c']))
print(Barney.answers)


Betty = OppMan()

print(Betty.echo('you figure it out'))
```

This one is like fractions, sort of:

```
class Rational:

    def __init__(self, numer, denom):
        self.n = numer
        self.d = denom



    def __add__(self, other):
        return Rational((self.n*other.d)+(self.d*other.n), self.d*other.d)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Rational(self.n*other.n, self.d*other.d)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n) + '/' + str(self.d)
```

Example usage:

```
foo = Rational(3,5)
bar = Rational(1,7)
print(foo+bar)


foo = Rational('3','5')
bar = Rational(1,2)
print(foo+bar)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the "room", dictionary, etc., but study these and try to find some simple problems to solve.  It might take a while to figure out how these work, but you'll know more about classes in the end.

Comment: Thank you. Do not worry it is not harsh. Like i said i'm just learning programming now for the first time and oop and classes have shocked me. Thanks for helping out. After reading alot yesterday and today I'm begining to understand. I just need to keep practicing. and again thank you.